# Getting item position 0 when clicking an item in ListView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-adapterview

I am trying to send an item position from a `Fragment` to an `Activity`, but I always get invoiceId `0` every time I select an item in listView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent seperateView = new Intent(rootView.getContext(),SeperateViewForDeliveryList.class);
            seperateView.putExtra("invoiceId", listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            startActivity(seperateView);
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(deliveryListAdapter);
    return rootView;
```

**In activity class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seperate_view_for_delivery_list);
    invoiceId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("invoiceId");
    Toast.makeText(this, "invoiceID " + invoiceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: change listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() to position.toString

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar how can you call like that?

Answer (score 0):

We can also pass integer value in an `Intent`. Try this:

```
seperateview.putExtra("invoiceId",listview.getItemAtPosition(position));
getIntent().getIntExtra("invoiceId",0);
```

Comment: still getting same '0' for invoiceID

Comment: `getItemAtPosition` returns an object of the data associated with the specified position in the list, so this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
seperateview.putExtra("invoiceId",String.valueOf(position));
```

Comment: from that `invoiceId` position how can I get that particular `InvoiceID` number

Comment: listview contains which kind of data? Which kind of arraylist you bind with listview?

Comment: It contains data in string format. calling data using PHP.  sample data looks like this '"invoiceId":"172","date":"2017-09-11"'

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent seperateview=new Intent(rootView.getContext(),SeperateViewForDeliveryList.class);
        seperateview.putExtra("invoiceId",parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        startActivity(seperateview);
    }
});
listview.setAdapter(deliveryListAdapter);
return rootView;
```

Try this

Comment: `getItemAtPosition` returns an object of the data associated with the specified position in the list, so this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`getItemAtPosition` returns an object of the data associated with the specified position in the list, while `position` itself is what you want.

Change your code to

```
seperateView.putExtra("invoiceId", String.valueOf(position));
```